# Make <div></div> floating inside table tr and td

Tags: html, css

I've done some coding and I am able to do autocomplete on php page. But unfortunately, when I typed something into the textbox, it does show what I need but the table is getting weird when it is shown :

[Weird Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYITj.png)

I wanted to make the  (customized with css) floating, like this :

[Correct element I wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMk2W.png)

Can anybody help me with this? I'm not pretty good at css, so here's the code :

```css
#material-list {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 190px;
}
#material-list li {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #FAFAFA;
  border-bottom: #F0F0F0 1px solid;
}
#material-list li:hover {
  background: #F0F0F0;
}
#search-box {
  padding: 10px;
  border: #F0F0F0 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#8eb4e3" class="td-data_1"><font size="2dp"><strong>Material Code</strong></font>
    </td>
    <td class="td-data_1">
      <div class="frmSearch">
        <input type="text" id="material_code" placeholder="Enter Material Name" style="font-size:13px; width: 215 " />
        <div id="suggesstion-box"></div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `#suggestion-box` in `absolute` `position`, so it doesn't interact within the flow of the page

```css
#material-list {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 190px;
}
#material-list li {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #FAFAFA;
  border-bottom: #F0F0F0 1px solid;
}
#material-list li:hover {
  background: #F0F0F0;
}
#search-box {
  padding: 10px;
  border: #F0F0F0 1px solid;
}
#suggesstion-box {position:absolute;
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#8eb4e3" class="td-data_1"><font size="2dp"><strong>Material Code</strong></font>
    </td>
    <td class="td-data_1">
      <div class="frmSearch">
        <input type="text" id="material_code" placeholder="Enter Material Name" style="font-size:13px; width: 215 " />
        <div id="suggesstion-box">whatever<br/>whatever </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```